# how to add marital status in Europasscv?

Tags: europasscv

i had already checked this question "how to add skype icon/ place of birth in Europasscv" but it's looking too complicated. i really don't have idea how to add marital status in Europasscv. i just typed as `\ecvmaritalstatus` and the output is `! Undefined control sequence. \ecvmaritalstatus`

```
\documentclass[12pt,german,black,nologo,notitle,a4paper,narrow]{europasscv}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\large}~~}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\ecvExtraRowHeight{0pt}
\ecvColSep{12pt}
\ecvRuleWidth{0.2pt}
\ecvLeftColumnWidth{6cm}

 \ecvname{Name }
 \ecvaddress{House No }
 \ecvtelephone[+00000000]{+00000000}
 \ecvemail{abd@gmail.com}
 \ecvgender{Male}
 \ecvnationality{name of country}
 \ecvdateofbirth{17.March 1987}
 \ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{-0.8cm}}

\begin{document}


  \begin{europasscv} 


\ecvpersonalinfo


   \end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's marital status doing on a cv?   That's probably why the package doesn't provide an \ecvmaritalstatus command.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official instructions](https://www.eeas.europa.eu/sites/default/files/europass_cv_instructions.pdf), page 12, the marital status, if you think it is important to specify it, should be stated in "Additional Information", and not in "Personal Information".

So even if it is (probably) technically possible to define a `\ecvmaritalstatus` command, don't do it, and simply add a remark in the "Additional Information" part of your CV.